# OAuth does not accept Non-top-level domain

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api, appdomain, whitelist

I have been using Google drive API since July and it accepted a non Top-Level local domain (not end with .com,.io,.org...)as whitelisted domain for OAuth.

But yesterday when I try to whitelist another domain, it shows that it doesn't allow non Top-Level Domain any longer.

Please assist on this because my entire company is using this non Top-Level domain internally. We can't afford to change the domain as it involved a lot of changes. Please advise what should I do.

Thanks.

Regards, Johnson

Comment: Hi there @JohnsonKhong ! Could you please clarify how did you whitelisted the domain? I was able to whitelist an `.eu` domain following [this](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6160020) guide.

Comment: I was trying to whitelist my domain "vecta.test" under OAuth Client in GCP. And it shows message "Invalid Origin: must end with a public top-level domain (such as .com or .org)."

Comment: To better help you, could you please confirm the outcome of the recommended guide? If that didn't help, please share the steps that you are following (or the code).